# How to make applozic chat private for each user?

Tags: web, applozic

How to make messages private that should be visible to only sender and receiver. Currently all message showing to all users.

Answer (score 0):

There is different [Group types](https://docs.applozic.com/v1.0/reference#group-types), the default is **Public Group** *type 2*.

You can specify the group type when you [create a group](https://docs.applozic.com/v1.0/reference#create-group), it might be *type 1* you will have to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ALMessage property Metadata. In this metadata you can pass your own Key/Value. using this pair you can identity chat is private or not.
While get message from message list you can check your key is there in metadata or not. if key is there in metadata it means message is private or you can add that chat in other list array.